# Add localization resources to be shared across multiple projects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Due to architecture design specifications, I have an application that fills its views from `ClassLibraries`. The application itself behaves like a sort of Integrator.

Now I need to add localization resources and I can successfully achieve it by adding `*.resw` files but **only if the control is declared inside of the Application project**.

What I actually need is to being able to share those resources across the **ENTIRE SOLUTION** somehow.

Then, the point is to being able to translate any control's content of the solution by using localization resources, preferably using the structure explained above.

For example, I have this following view, which fills the `TextBlocks`' content depending on the selected language:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Languages"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <iCore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <iCore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeLanguage}" />
            </iCore:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LanguageName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.HelloText}" FontSize="50" Foreground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.HowAreYouText}" FontSize="50" Foreground="Red"/>
    <BFview:BFView />
</StackPanel>
```

Where `BFView` is a view stored in another project (has two dummy textblocks also)

The `Model` of that view:

```
public class MainModel : TranslatableStrings
    {
        private string helloText, howareuText;

        public string HelloText
        {
            get { return this.helloText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.helloText, value); }
        }

        public string HowAreYouText
        {
            get { return this.howareuText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.howareuText, value); }
        }

    }
```

And the base class of the `Model` is just a contractual class since it has no implementation, but a base type:

```
public abstract class TranslatableStrings : BindableBase { }
```

Then, the `View` data context is the following one:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MainViewListRscs> languages = new ObservableCollection<MainViewListRscs>();
        private ICommand changeLang;
        private MainModel model = new MainModel();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Languages = new ObservableCollection<MainViewListRscs>()
            {
                new MainViewListRscs { LanguageCode = "es-ES", LanguageName = "Español" },
                new MainViewListRscs { LanguageCode = "en-EN", LanguageName = "English" },
                new MainViewListRscs { LanguageCode = "fr-FR", LanguageName = "Français" },
                new MainViewListRscs { LanguageCode = "de-DE", LanguageName = "Deutsch" }
            };

        }

        public ICommand ChangeLanguage
        {
            get { return changeLang = changeLang ?? new DelegateCommand(OnChangeLanguageRequested); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MainViewListRscs> Languages
        {
            get { return this.languages; }
            set
            {
                this.languages = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewListRscs SelectedLanguage { get; set; }

        public MainModel Model
        {
            get { return this.model; }
            set { this.model = value; }
        }

        private void OnChangeLanguageRequested()
        {
            Logger.Debug("MAINVIEW", SelectedLanguage.LanguageName + " selected.");
            TranslateManager.UpdateStrings<TranslatableStrings>(SelectedLanguage.LanguageCode, this.Model);
        }

        public override Task OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override Task OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And the `TranslateManager`:

```
public class TranslateManager
    {
        public async static void UpdateStrings<T>(string langCode, T instance) where T : TranslatableStrings
        {
            //Get all the classes that implement TranslatableStrings
            var currentAssembly = instance.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var translatableClasses = currentAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(T)).ToList();

            //Open RESX file
            ResourceLoader resx = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(langCode);

            foreach(var Class in translatableClasses)
            {
                foreach(var property in Class.DeclaredProperties)
                {
                    string value = resx.GetString(property.Name);
                    var vmProp = instance.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(property.Name);
                    vmProp.SetValue(instance, value);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I have achieved changing the two `TextBlocks` of the `MainView` but not the view in another project. What I would need to do is to get a list of assemblies contained in a solution. I guess that getting just this would make everything work since I'm using a generic implementation.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your translation files are loaded as resources. So you can access them anywhere, even in other projects by doing something like

```
private ResourceLoader _resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
var someTranslation =_resourceLoader.GetString("your_localization_key");
```

Wrap this code nicely into a lib so that you can have an easy access to it from everywhere, and there you go !

Comment: Thank you for replying! I've been working in a solution implementing the translation in the way you suggested me but now I think I have a mental block... See updated question